# cant connect vs2012 to TFS on cloud with windows server 2012 on VirtualMachine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, cloud, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012

I am working with windows server 2012 on Virtual Machine VMWARE.
I am using visual studio 2012 for developing sharepoint 2013 projects
My problem is that I have an error message when I try to connect to TFS on cloud , I am using the same URL with a project on Visual studio 2010 on Windows 7 and it's working fine.
URL: mycompany.visualstudio.com

Error :TF31002 unable to connect to this team foundation server : https://mycompany.visualstudio.com

but this error is different than other posts about TF31002 on stackoverflow because it is working fine with Visual studio 2010 on Windows 7

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility problem. 
When it occurs: Connect TFS 2012 or newer with VS2010.

Solution:

Step 1 - Install Visual Studio SP1 
link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Step 2 - Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR
link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082

I hope this trick helps!
Good luck!